# Convert separate date and time data types to the format I want to use in my table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time, format

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to complete my queries.

The information I have found to get the date format and time format is:

```
SELECT FORMAT (GETDATE(), 'dd-MM-yyyy') AS date

SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'HH:mm') AS time
```

Which takes the current date and time and presents it to me in the format I need but I am wondering how do I apply this to my data in the table I am creating?

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule 
(
    movieID INT,
    screeningID INT,
    date DATE,
    time TIME,

    FOREIGN KEY (movieID) REFERENCES Movie (movieID),
    FOREIGN KEY (screeningID) REFERENCES MovieScreening (screeningID)
);
```

Here is the data I want to insert:

```
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (1, 1, '14-03-2020', '11AM') 
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (2, 2, '14-03-2020', '12PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (3, 3, '14-03-2020', '1PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (4, 4, '14-03-2020', '2PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (5, 5, '14-03-2020', '3PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (6, 6, '14-03-2020', '4PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (7, 7, '14-03-2020', '5PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (8, 8, '14-03-2020', '6PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (9, 9, '14-03-2020', '7PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (10, 10, '14-03-2020', '8PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (1, 11, '15-03-2020', '11AM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (2, 12, '15-03-2020', '12PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (3, 13, '15-03-2020', '1PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (4, 14, '15-03-2020', '12PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (5, 15, '15-03-2020', '3PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (6, 16, '15-03-2020', '4PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (7, 17, '15-03-2020', '5PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (8, 18, '15-03-2020', '6PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (9, 19, '15-03-2020', '7PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES (10, 20, '15-03-2020', '8PM')
```

And this is the output I am getting when I tested the format code and select the table I created as above.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgsgN.png)

I've been trying to figure this out on my own and searching online for a solution that I could apply to my own work but I could use some help as I'm kind of lost.

**EDIT:** So I commented one one of the answers and I just want to clarify my use-case and the reason behind keeping my date, and time separate.

So my use-case is for a movie schedule and I need the date and time to be separate so a search query can be made to find details linked to a specific time or on a specific date and because the schedule has the exact same timetable for each day I need them as separated data types. I have five tables in this database and I have two other tables that are linked to this schedule table; One is a list of movies and the other holds movie screening details like ticket prices, the movieID and a TheatreID which connects a table with a list of theatres and information on those theatres.

If it helps [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qndkD.png) is the data model I made before I created the database tables in excel, but the only issue I've come across is getting my date's and time's to display up how I want them.

**I want to be able to call on data for example:**

```
    SELECT Schedule.movieID, Schedule.time
    FROM Schedule
    WHERE (Schedule.time = '11AM')
```

When I run this I get a return table that looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlsWU.png)

Whereas I would prefer if the time column returned the data as 'hh:mm' I'm just unsure how to get it to do that, is there a time datatype that will only return 'hh:mm' ?

Comment: As you are new, just checking that you are familiar with what to do [when someone answers](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stackoverflow+when+someone+answers&atb=v216-1&ia=web)

Answer (score 3):

So the `date`, `time` and `datetime` datatypes are not stored internally with any formatting. Formatting is a function of displaying the data.

And you should always use the `date`, `time` and `datetime` datatypes where relevant because the alternative, storing them as a string, introduces quite a number of issues further down the line.

Displaying of the data should be left to the application really, however if you want to format it as part of a query then thats up to you, but instead of

```
select *
from Schedule;
```

use

```
select id, FORMAT([date], 'dd-MM-yyyy'), FORMAT([time], 'HH:mm')
from Schedule;
```

Comment: I agree with this but also with @Wouter.  I don't see any reason not to merge both date/time into a single cell and then format them on retrieval.

Comment: @NathanChampion thats not what the OP is asking though - the answer to their question is the same regardless as to whether they use date+time or datetime - use format as part of the select. And as I don't know their use-case I'm not about to advise one way or the other.

Comment: @NathanChampion I suspect "And its totally 100% correct to store it that way" didn't communicate what I meant - I was endorsing OP **not** using a string :) not suggesting `date`+`time` was better than `datetime`.

Comment: So my use-case is for a movie schedule and I need the date and time to be separate so a search query can be made to find details linked to a specific time or on a specific date and because the schedule has the exact same timetable for each day I need them as separated data types. I have five tables in this database and I have two other tables that are linked to this schedule table; One is a list of movies and the other is a list of theatres. I want to be able to call on data for example:
'''
SELECT Schedule.movieID, Schedule.time
FROM Schedule
WHERE (Schedule.time = '11AM')
'''

Comment: @Faith great - and does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Store your date and time in a column with datetime datatype. The formatting should not be stored in your database. Apply the format when you display the date in your application or report.

Answer (score -1):

you should consider that SQL format for DATE type is YYYY-MM-DD, which you can change only while querying for selection or filtering
otherwise, if you keep your format stored in the Database you should store them in NVachar type of other string type column

Comment: You should **NEVER** store date or time information as `NVARCHAR`! And the SQL format for DATE type is most definitely not YYYY-MM-DD - that might be the default display format, but it is certainly not stored in that format.